# Is Android Studio better than Unity3d for augmented reality apps?

Tags: augmented-reality

I want to create for all platforms. I can go from android to ios to windows etc. But which platform is best suited for creating the app. Or any other platform to consider. What do other developers use?

Answer (score 0):

I would say Unity as you are looking to port your project onto multiple devices. Unity can build projects onto multiple platforms very easily, which you then can export into android studio or swift to "play" your project.

While it is easy enough to export the project onto multiple platforms, this does not mean it will natively work straight out of the box when you export it to android studio/swift. You would still need to program your input controls and resolve resolutions when porting to smaller devices etc. Depending if you are going to use dense 3d models within your augmented app, you would also need to consider the polygon count on the 3d models when porting to other less powerful devices which can have a significant impact on performance.

Comment: Or any other platform to consider. What do other developers use?

Comment: You could check out Xamarin Studio. It is designed to have one code base for both android and apple apps. I havent used it myself but  I have heard alot of good things about it.

Comment: What do other developers use?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. For multiplatform apps its pretty much an industry standard to either use an IDE that handles multiplatform programming (Unity, Xamarin), or independantly have seperate code bases, one for android, one for mac, one for pc etc, but this is a far more tedious task and it would involve coding your project from java, to objective C, to C# (if using unity)

Comment: Other developers like google or samsung or and other ar development company?

Comment: High chance they will be using their own in house tools for the development which would not be  known to the public. Furthermore google would be using a massive range of languages for the development work.